# verificar se metodo no backend é true e no client também

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Eu tenho um codigo que no meu backend ele retorna true ou false, estou trabalhando com ruby e rails 5.

então eu tenho la um if mais ou menos assim ja:

```
<% if @order? %>
    <h2> teste 2 <h2>
<%else>
    <h1>teste 1</h1>
<%end>
```

porem o que quero fazer é o seguinte se for true no backend verificar se no frontend tambem é e adicionar o resultado true ou false dentro desse if no .erb

algo assim:

```
<% if @order? && var ou algo que retornar true no lado do client  %>
    <h2> teste 2 <h2>
<%else>
    <h1>teste 1</h1>
<%end>
```

Se tiverem outra ideia de como fazer isso tbm, sera muito bem vinda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é uma péssima prática. Porém, lá vai:

```html
<script>
if(<%@order> === variavelClient && variavelClient){
console.log('são iguais e verdadeiras')
}
</script>
```